# Mac mini as linux server, no keyboard and usb boot

Tags: ubuntu, mac

I am going to buy a mac mini (mid 2010 no server edition) and use it as linux server (i think i will use ubuntu server as distribution on it).

I never had any mac so sorry if i ask some newbie/dummy questions but just to make sure before buy it:

- can it boot from usb key (for the installation) ?
- can it boot without keyboard/mouse/monitor ?
- the bios is a standard bios like a pc ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes it can boot from a usb
- Yes it can boot without a keyboard/mouse/monitor
- No there is no normal pc type bios on a mac.

Comment: About the bios, how can i setup it to "boot from cd" or "boot from usb" ?  on pc i setup this on bios, it has a custom bios from apple or similar?

Comment: Booting from [USB storage](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1948) is tricky.  Booting from a CD is pretty easy.  Just put in a disk and hold down **C** [during startup](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1533).

Answer (score 0):

> can it boot from usb key (for the installation) ?

Yes, hold Alt key on boot until the chime and choose boot medium.

> can it boot without keyboard/mouse/monitor ?

Yes, but it conflicts with usb boot ;) - But theres no "Press F1 for continue" dialogue on Mac

> the bios is a standard bios like a pc ?

No, its a special EFI. You'll also need a special bootloader.

Comment: EFI is a replacement for BIOS, not a kind of BIOS :)

Comment: @FrandsHansen True Point :) - I'll edit this.